# FormsAuthentication roles the user was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am having problems with my FormsAuthentication, for some reason whey i try to give roles to my user i get the error "The user 'X' was not found.". This error makes no sense as i have just added the user the line before.

The following code

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(member.Id.ToString(), true);
Roles.AddUserToRole(member.Id.ToString(), "Admin");
```

Gives me the error (member.Id is 3)

```
The user '3' was not found
```

**Edit:** There is no requirement for the username to actuly be the username, it just has to match what i set as the users username in the FormsAuthentication! It is commen practice to use the users id instead (transformed to a string)! But this dose still not change my problem, so my user’s name is ”3”!

This is done at user login:

```
// Set roles
foreach(var r in Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.Id.ToString()))
    Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(user.Id.ToString(), r);
IList<UserRole> roles = _usersServices.GetUserRoles((int)user.Id);
foreach (var userRole in roles)
{
    if(userRole.Expires == null || userRole.Expires > DateTime.Now)
    {
        if(!Roles.RoleExists(userRole.Name))
            Roles.CreateRole(userRole.Name);
        Roles.AddUserToRole(user.Id.ToString(), userRole.Name);
    }
}
```

**Solution:** The problem was that i had forgot to set the roleManager in my web.config, so even though i populated my values at userlogin, did they have nowhere to be stored!

Comment: Your users username is 3?

Comment: @DoomStone seems to be under the impression AddUserToRole takes an id instead of a username. I agree it should. I feel the entire Membership API should have been designed around id's more than strings.

Comment: @Doomstone: In response to your Edit, THERE IS A REQUIREMENT FOR USERNAME TO BE A NAME. if you check aspnetmembership table, it matches a username with a role name. using !'s and down-voting ppl who try to help you won't resolve your coding problems. Coding takes patience and research.

Comment: @DoomStone, you should read up on Membership API. AddUserToRole takes username, not a userid converted to a string

Comment: I am not using the build in ForumAuth, so i am simply adding users on the fly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed my role manager in `web.config` and now it works.

It was:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add
            name="DefaultRoleProvider"
            type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
            applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now it is:

```
<roleManager
    enabled="true"
    cacheRolesInCookie="true"
    cookieName=".ASPXROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30"
    cookiePath="/"
    cookieRequireSSL="false"
    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All"
    defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
    createPersistentCookie="false"
    maxCachedResults="25" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. `Roles.AddUserToRole` takes a string (`username`) and a role (`rolename`). You are correctly passing the Role as a string, but incorrectly passing the `userid` instead of the username.

change your code:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole({username}, "Admin");
```

Comment: There is no requirement for the username to actuly be a username! It is commen practice to use the users id instead (transformed to a string)! But this dose still not change my problem, so my user’s name is ”3”!

Comment: @DoomStone, please read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx ... if your username was really 3, your call should be successfull. But then why are you making a call for member.Id.ToString()?

Comment: There are 2 lines in my code, the first adds the user with the username "3", the next simply gives username "3" role "Admin"

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.I was changed the **applicationName** value of some properties in **Web.Config**.If you changed it then you have to change all application variables values.

I changed them all and it is OK now.